# What's exactly a source file for the C11 standard

Tags: c, c11

I've a doubt about a sentence in this paragraph of the standard C11:

**5.1.1.1 Program structure**

> A C program need not all be translated at the same time. The text of
>   the program is kept in units called source ﬁles, (or preprocessing
>   ﬁles) in this International Standard. A source ﬁle together with all
>   the headers and source ﬁles included via the preprocessing directive #include is known as a preprocessing translation unit.

At first it says that the text of a program is kept in units called source files.
After it says that a source file together with headers and source files are said to be preprocessing translation unit.

So is a source file a different entity respect to a header file or a source file include both?

Comment: its just saying a source file can have multiple other files included into it, headers, other source files, and once all of that has been included, then thats a PTU

Comment: So it seems as for you a source file is a different entity respect to a header file...

Answer (score 4):

A *source file* is any text file (or other implementation-specific entity, per Basile's answer) containing source code. This specifically includes both `.c` and `.h` files. It might also includes files with other suffixes, like preprocessor or generated-code files.

When you take some source file actually passed to the compiler (so usually only `.c` files), that file together with (the transitive closure of) everything it `#include`s forms a *translation unit*.

So: every translation unit is built of source files.

But: not every source file is the starting point of a translation unit.

Answer (score 2):

Pedantically, a source file (in the sense of C99 or C11 standard) is not even necessarily a file (in the operating system sense). A conforming implementation could read the "source file" from a database or some constant string inside some program.

<sup>A proprietary IBM compiler in the 1990s ([VisualAge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_VisualAge)???) is rumored to have obtained the source to compile from some database. Today, [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) also provides a `libtcc` library with a function `tcc_compile_string` to compile a string. TinyCC is compiling very quickly into *slow* machine code.</sup>

Practically, there are often several source files (like `.h` & `.c` files) which are processed within the same compilation or [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit).

<sup>IIUC, the funny thing about the C standards is that they don't suppose a filesystem for the implementation to have. I believe the standard don't even require a computer; you might implement the standard unethically using a bunch of human slaves, but that is immoral and inefficient.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The term *source file* (or *preprocessing ﬁle*) reflects to both `.c` source file and `.h` header. The C Standard does not differentiate them as such.

It is explicitely mentioned in K. N. King's "C Programming: A Modern Approach" book (section 15.2).

Comment: This is an interesting point; the standard also says: "A header is not necessarily a source ﬁle, nor are the < and > delimited sequences in header names necessarily valid source ﬁle names.". ...